# CLI that find the Pictures folder of the operating system

Tags: python-3.x

How can I get this program to find the `Pictures` folder on any operating system? E.g. Windows, Linux, and Mac.

My program will just take an input and create a `QRcode` image.

I know there are some standard modules to help me, like `os` and `sys`, but I wasn't able to figure it out on my own.

```py
import qrcode

data = 'This is an example.'
qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1)
qr.add_data(data)
img = qr.make_image(fill_color='white', back_color='purple')
img.save('$HOME/Pictures/qrcode_make_python.png')
```

Comment: What are the assumptions you're making here? Like you want the `%USERPROFILE%/Pictures` in Windows? And `${HOME}/Pictures` under MacOS? (Don't think there's a 'default' for any general Linux distro, though).

Comment: Yes, I would like it to work for both Windows and Mac. I know Linux will be a little more difficult.

Comment: @WesleyBlake Actually it's pretty easy, `~` for home and for the `Pictures` directory it's `~/Pictures`

Comment: That is all you need to find the Pictures folder for all OS's?

Comment: Yes, and also check out my answer down below

Comment: @WesleyBlake - In many *nix distros, there isn’t a default (standard) Pictures directory, as there is on Win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pathlib.Path.home()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home) for that.

Here is an example:

```
from qrcode import QRCode
from pathlib import Path

pictures_folder = Path.home() / 'Pictures'

if pictures_folder.is_dir():
    data = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
    qr = QRCode(version=1)
    qr.add_data(data)
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color='white', back_color='purple')

    img.save(pictures_folder / 'qrcode.png')
else:
    print(f"{pictures_folder} folder doesn't exist!")
```

The snippet above is portable and will work on most platforms supported by Python.

Comment: This works and only took two lines. Thumbs up!